# Should I use Fermaid-O or Fermaid-K while fermenting mead?

Tags: mead, yeast-nutrient

I've been making a mead for last two years, and a huge supporter of staggered nutrients additions to mead where you use Go-Ferm to rehydrate the yeast, adjust pH level with potassium carbonate, and some pectin enzymes with fruit additions.

Also, I'm using Fermaid-K and DAP on days 2-4-6 when the yeasts are strong and healthy enough.

I've been reading that a new trend is substituting Fermaid-K for Fermaid-O (O for organic).

I'm not quite sure how much Fermaid-O should I use per gallon. Since it doesn't contain any DAP in it, amount of DAP should increase, but buy how much? 
How much of DAP should I add on days 2-4-6 per gallon? 
Since there is no DAP in Fermaid-O it can be added all at once on day 0... What's the appropriate amount?

Oh, and the main question, is it worth it substituting Fermaid-O for Fermaid-K at all?

Thanks, guys.

Comment: My question is how is all this affecting the flavor of the mead? I use pollen as a nutrient.

Comment: If used in exact amounts, it should not affect the taste (yeast would consume all of it). I assume if you overuse it, it might create sulfite off flavors, but I never ran in to this problem yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How much Fermaid-O do you need?**

The amount of required nutrient addition is based on your starting gravity. For an easier calculation convert to Brix and figure out your target mg of nitrogen per liter using the following as a starting point:

21°Bx = 200 mg N/L

23°Bx = 250 mg N/L

25°Bx = 300 mg N/L

27°Bx = 350 mg N/L

1g/gal of Fermaid-O = 50ppm (or mg) of N/L effectiveness
(always measure by weight, invest in a good grams scale)

Source - http://www.meadmaderight.com/info.html

**Should you substitute?**

This is more of a personal question.  I've used DAP/Ferment-K for years.  I've also debated the same thing you are.  I think I will make the switch when I run out of Ferment-K / DAP.

It seems like the advantage is: "TOSNA uses only Fermaid-O because of its organic form of nitrogen which the yeast is easily able to metabolize throughout the entire fermentation process, unlike the inorganic form of nitrogen provided by the use of DAP and/or Fermaid-K." - [source](http://www.meadmaderight.com/home.html)

Comment: Thanks. Also http://www.meadmakr.com/ has a calculator for it.